# Laravel : Carbon shorten diffForHumans()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

How can we trim down `diffForHumans()` ?

Like `$post->created_at->diffForHumans()` return the time ago Like `3 days ago` or `57 minutes ago`, or `2 hours ago`.

How can we be able to return `57 mins ago` or `1W ago` etc.

**Is there any way around ?**

> Searched around but got nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Carbon implements different call-time configurations through magic methods. The universe of possible configurations are documented in the [backing trait](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/713c4019b8b53d22f220f4abbaf433205c13e872/src/Carbon/Traits/Date.php#L478). Scanning through those methods, it looks like you want `shortRelativeDiffForHumans`:

```
$c = new Carbon\Carbon('now -1 day 4 hours');                                    
dump($c->diffForHumans(), $c->shortRelativeDiffForHumans());                     

"20 hours ago"
"20h ago"
```

Failing that, you can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or similar string functions to adjust the resulting value.

I'll note, in response to [@Giovanni's contribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52371389/2908724), that these magic methods are just verbose wrappers around the call to `diffForHumans`. I prefer these longer method names and their variations, because they're self-documenting. Using `diffForHumans` third argument of `true` doesn't tell me much when scanning code a year later!

Answer (score 7):

The third value passed to diffForHumans() is for shortening the display output.

Try something like,

```
$post->created_at->diffForHumans(null, false, true)
```

here you can see a the comments for diffForHumans() and the values it accepts.

---

```
     /**
     * Get the difference in a human readable format in the current locale.
     *
     * When comparing a value in the past to default now:
     * 1 hour ago
     * 5 months ago
     *
     * When comparing a value in the future to default now:
     * 1 hour from now
     * 5 months from now
     *
     * When comparing a value in the past to another value:
     * 1 hour before
     * 5 months before
     *
     * When comparing a value in the future to another value:
     * 1 hour after
     * 5 months after
     *
     * @param Carbon|null $other
     * @param bool        $absolute removes time difference modifiers ago, after, etc
     * @param bool        $short    displays short format of time units
     * @param int         $parts    displays number of parts in the interval
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function diffForHumans($other = null, $absolute = false, $short = false, $parts = 1)
    {
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```
shortRelativeDiffForHumans()
```

[Docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff)

Answer (score -1):

`{{ $product->created_at->diffForHumans(null, false, 1) }}`

**Result**: 14h ago, 14m ago, etc....

Comment: How is this different from the top-voted answer?

Comment: Slightly different syntax? Can you not see the difference?

Comment: You mean using `1` instead of `true`? That just gets coerced to `true`. It has nothing to do with the question. In any case, when providing an answer that is just slightly different from existing ones (especially very highly rated answers) please take a moment to draw attention to the difference and explain how it is better. "Slightly different syntax" without any context does not justify a new answer.